# Microsoft database synchronization

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, synchronization, offline

I have the following scenario:

**Server**

- SQL Server 2008
- Core (Entity Framework and business logic)
- WCF Service
- MVC Web application (for backend management)

**Client**

- Local Database - a simplified model of the main database
- WPF Client

**Requirements**

- The client has to work fully offline, and persist data
- Changed data should be pulled from the server over WCF service
- Client should not change the data, but call a a WCF method (if not available queue the call)

**Possible Solutions**

- Microsoft Sync Framework - I think its an overkill, because I mainly need one way synching, and also the data structure is not the same.
- Datasets serialization over WCF, yes, because Datasets support merging and offline scenarios, but isn't It out of date?
- Entity Framework? I tried to build a prototype, but EF doesn't seem to support my needs very well (I need to search for an entity, and change it if modified, or add it if not existant)

**Question**

- What, do you think, is the most appropriate approach?
- Is SQL Server Compact a good local db?

I am very interested in your thoughts. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Sync Framework is in my opinion not appropriate because you have differing schemas. I can also imagine that you have some business rules about what data is allowed to change and how it should be synced.

The choice between DataSets and Entity Framework depends on your needs. An Object-Relation-Mapper comes in to view when you are really using an object model.

If your domain is complex enough and you have the knowledge using a full fledged Domain Model is definitely a nice solution that can scale really well and handle complex projects.
If your project is somewhat simpler and you don't want to build a Domain Model you can choose for DataSets.

Personally, I think that learning the ins and outs of Domain Modeling and the Entity Framework as an ORM is a nice choice for projects. When you have enough experience using these technologies, you will even favor them on small projects.

About the problems you where having with your EF prototype.

Because the data schema of the client and the server is different I would use custom Data Transfer Objects for moving data between the two. This way, you decouple the object models and they can change independent of each other.

The client knows everything there is to know about the data changes. Because it has a local representation of the server data it knows if data is added, changed or deleted. Why don't you add this knowledge to your server call? If you use a field in your DTO that states if the object is Added, Modified or Deleted, the server won't have to detect this.

Comment: Thank you for your well thought answer. In my Prototype, I actually created a Dto Object for Transfer. This transfer-Object I also used as a Entity to store on client -side. I wanted to choose a preferably simple approach. The client does need the data only for lookup. The only changes it makes, are transactions, and these I'd preferably process on the server.